# Kerberos setup on Red Hat

Tags: kerberos

I'm using Red Hat 5 client to authenticate to a Windows 2003 KDC (or trying to anyway), but when I run

```
kinit vwwebseal@VWXAUTHN.LOCAL
```

I get

```
kinit(v5): Cannot find KDC for requested realm while getting initial credentials
```

When I use nslookup, the Red Hat machine can successfully look up the KDC:

```
[root@vwwebseal ~]# nslookup vwkdc.vwxauthn.local
Server:         10.150.26.64
Address:        10.150.26.64#53

Name:   vwkdc.vwxauthn.local
Address: 10.150.26.64
```

This is my krb5.conf file:

> [libdefaults]
>          default_realm = VWXAUTHN.LOCAL
>          default_keytab_name = FILE:/etc/krb5/krb5.keytab
>          default_tkt_enctypes = rc4-hmac
>          default_tgs_enctypes = rc4-hmac
>
> [realms]
>          VWXAUTHN.LOCAL = {
>                  kdc = vwkdc.vwxauthn.local:88
>                  admin_server = vwkdc.vwxauthn.local:749
>                  default_domain = vwxauthn.local
>          }
>
> [domain_realm]
>          .vwxauthn.local = VWXAUTHN.LOCAL
>          vwkdc.vwxauthn.local = VWXAUTHN.LOCAL
>
> [logging]
>          kdc = FILE:/var/krb5/log/krb5kdc.log
>          admin_server = FILE:/var/krb5/log/kadmin.log
>          default = FILE:/var/krb5/log/krb5lib.log

Comment: _When I use nslookup, the Red Hat machine can successfully look up the KDC (vwkdc.vwxauthn.local)._ --> Could you please show us the output?

Comment: Check /etc/hosts (or run getent hosts vwkdc.vwxauthn.local) if nsswitch.conf means kerberos uses the hosts file rather than DNS to look for the KDC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's okay, I solved it.  When I ran config.krb5 it created a file at /etc/krb5/krb5.conf, but a file already existed at /etc/krb5.conf.  It was using that configuration instead of the one I created, so I removed /etc/krb5.conf.